# Fetching complete rows based on unique values from a non-unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database in SQLServer in which there are multiple rows for a database named emp_details. The table contains several fields, one of which is salary. The salary is not unique for the employees, and I need to fetch one complete row for each unique salary value.

Kindly let me know the query which may help.

A sample of the database:

```
a   b       c   d       e   f

17  IL11    53  IL11    48  58
26  IL10    53  IL10    48  58
31  IL15    53  IL15    48  58
32  IL16    53  IL16    24  58
33  IL17    53  IL17    36  58
34  IL18    53  IL18    36  58
37  IL21    53  IL21    36  58
40  IL24    53  IL24    48  58
```

I want to filter this on column e (assume it to be salary field)

Comment: one complete row corresponding to all the unique salaries, not just one

Comment: Do you only want the rows that have salaries that are not repeated anywhere else?

Comment: Yes! Only those rows that have salaries that are not repeated anywhere else in that field

Comment: can you post the schema of emp details?

Comment: The data is a help but could you please describe what the result set should look like too for a query. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure if this is better performance wise as there is no schema. But this should work.

```
WITH Emp_Salary
AS
(
    SELECT 
        Column1
        , Column2
        , Salary
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Salary ORDER BY Column1) r  --numbers each row uniquely per salary
        FROM emp_details
)
SELECT
    Column1
    , Column2
    , Salary
FROM Emp_Salary
WHERE r = 1 -- Filters all but the first row per salary.
;
```

Comment: Invalid column name 'r' is what I'm getting

Comment: My Mistake, Outer query is not referencing the CTE. Corrected it now

Comment: I doubt this is what OP wants. To OP: If frank earns 100$ and pete earns 100$, this will return one record (with either frank or pete depending on order by clause).

Comment: That is how I read it.

"The salary is not unique for the employees, and I need to fetch one complete row for each unique salary value"

Guess we will have to wait for clarification

Comment: @AllyReilly: what is Emp_Salary? Is it the same as Salary?

Comment: Hi, Emp_salary is a common table expression which I have declared in the WITH (SELECT....) block of code. common table expressions or CTEs are a way of declaring a table like structure which can be referenced else where in the query. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Comment: @rahulritesh, do you realize you selected the wrong answer as the right one?

Comment: Sorry, I see now that he sent you a link.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    emp_details
WHERE
    Salary IN(
              SELECT
                  Salary
              FROM
                  emp_details
              GROUP BY  
                   Salary
              HAVING
                    COUNT(*) = 1
              )
```

Comment: Got just 1 row in the result!

Comment: @rahulritesh - We can't see your data but the statement is correct. It means there is only **one** unique salary in your entire table.

Comment: Sorry, but as I said, there are multiple unique salaries in the field

Comment: @rahulritesh - That statement doesn't make sense to me. We can play the guessing game all day but if you would post a *(minimum and only relevant)* sample of your data and the expected output, I'm sure it will clear everything up.

Comment: @rahulritesh - What is the salary column? e? What is your expected output?

Comment: 'e' is the Salary Column. I want to get the complete rows with a = 17, 32 and 33, since these three have different values of e, and are the first to occur

Comment: @Lieven: Thanks for your help, man! Sorry, if I screwed you up. Allen's answer worked

Answer (score 0):

`select distinct salary from emp_details` will give you a range of salary values.

To get the other rows... how do you want to chose which row you want?

if you have a PK of ID you could do

`select * from emp_details where id in 
(
select Max(id),Salary from emp_details
group by salary 
)`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the IN operator if your inner query will return many rows. 
Also, count(*) will be a lot slower than count(id).

This one might be faster:

```
SELECT emp.*
  FROM emp_details emp
    WHERE exists (SELECT a 
                    from emp_details
                    where e = emp.e
                    group by e
                      having count(a) = 1
                 );
```